# How can I find the position of several repeated highest values in a table?

Tags: lua, find, lua-table

I have a table in Lua with, for example:

```
Array = {5,3,5}
```

And I want, if possible, a function that returns the position of the highest values.

Probably an easy question but I cannot find the solution...

Comment: So, what output do you expect in your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`math.max`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.max) returns the maximum value. To get the index:

```
local t = {5,3,5}
local max = math.max(table.unpack(t))
for i, v in ipairs(t) do
    if v == max then
        print(i)
    end
end
```

Note that the table is passed twice here. If the table is huge, pass the table once and store the highest value and compare manually.

Comment: Super thanks!!! I hope one day to be as good as the worse of any of you!! Amazing!! :)

Comment: If the table is huge, `table.unpack` will fail.